# How to generate AxInterop files?

Tags: interop

We have a .NET project that relies on an old VB6 OCX (The entire thing was originally VB6 and C++ and we are gradually migrating it all to .Net but we need it working in its present half-migrated state). One of our developers can build the project but no-one else can.

The developer finds that he has references to an interop.foo.dll file and an AxInterop.foo.dll, both of which exist.

I have built the VB6 project and added a reference to the OCX into my copy of the .NET project by browsing to it. I now have a reference to the interop.foo.dll, which exists, but I do not have a reference to the AxInterop.foo.dll and that file does not exist either. I also have errors like "Type 'AxFoo.AxocxFoo' is not defined" which stop the project building.

How would I go about generating this AxInterop.foo.dll file and referencing it? I can see lots of StackOverflow questions about what these files are but nothing saying how they are generated!

Many thanks,

--- Alistair.

Comment: I think I have found it: aximp.exe. Will post a proper answer once I have confirmed that it works.

Comment: I am not allowed to answer my own question for another few hours, but I think I have solved it: the solution is to use the AXIMP.EXE command-line tool. For further info, follow these links:

[Equivalent question and answer on a Microsoft forum][1]


[MSDN page about AXImp.exe][2]


  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/badd8a78-0e7b-4d76-86ae-faf184654d02
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 3):

> I have solved it: the solution is to use the `aximp.exe`command-line tool.

**References**

- [Equivalent question and answer on a Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/badd8a78-0e7b-4d76-86ae-faf184654d02)
- [MSDN page about aximp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774)(Windows Forms ActiveX Control Importer)